# Does lucene support phrase-indexing?

Tags: lucene

Can lucene be configured to perform phrase-indexing? For example, can lucene be configured to index noun-phrase embedded in the web page? Alternatively, can anyone recommend a open-source for indexing noun-phrase embedded in web page. Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by a noun phrase?

Comment: A noun phrase basically is a phrase comprising string of at least one word. A noun phrase is classified or recognize as a noun by the grammar for the corresponding sentence embedded with the phrase. For example: the phrase of "President of the United States" is a noun phrase comprising multiple words. Another example: The phrase of "planet earth" is another noun phrase comprising the word of "planet" and"earth".

Answer (score 0):

Lucene can index phrases, but Lucene does not specifically recognize noun phrases vs. verb phrases vs. other phrases. For example, "He hit the ball with the bat" could be indexed so that you could find "he hit", "hit the", "the ball", "ball with", "with the', and "the bat" as 2-word phrases.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there any open source tool out there can be used specifically for indexing noun-phrase or extract noun phrase? Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend -- search for something like "noun phrase tagging" (possibly along with "Java").